# Android Beginner Tips

Tags: android

I am a newbie to Android and want to explore. I see samples that I can workout from the documentation, But I am keen on developing a top to bottom sliding drawer instead of the left to right Navigation drawer. All I can see from the reference documentation are classes methods and their function. Please give me tips on how to work with these methods without seeing the samples. All I want is to be a good programmer and learn to code myself. Is that possible.

Comment: Have you actually built anything off of these samples?

Comment: There are at least 3 reasons to put this question on hold: (1) you are not specific so it is unclear what you're asking, (2) at this form this question is too broad, (3) and primarily opinion-based. Please improve your question.

Comment: @Evan, Usually I download samples and import them in eclipse.

Comment: @Pshemo, Sorry since I am a newbie I wanted to understand the coding methods, and how do dev's do it. please guide me.

Comment: Unfortunately this kind of question are not good for SO. Consider posting it on other sites like http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ (although I am not sure if it is correct one).

Comment: Read some books, follow some sites like vogella, androider, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this open source project **Clean Calculator** that contains a bottom to top navigation drawer you can download it and see the code how it was written, also to have a good start you might like to follow the android training classes [Android site](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html), also you can see this book [Android for Programmers: An App-Driven Approach (Deitel Developer Series)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132121360)
 which is very good when you learn the basics, the following book too is good [Beginning Android 4 Application Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118199545), and [Androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/) contains many tutorials too

Comment: Please flag it if it is helpful to let other know this